# Distance between a point and a MultiPolygon Geoseries object in Python

Tags: python, polygon, distance, geopandas, shapely

I want to calculate the distance of a point from the Multiploygon geoseries object created using cascaded_union function of GeoPandas. Following is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point, MultiPoint

fp = "\\TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3\\TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp"
data = gpd.read_file(fp)

mycountries = ['Canada','Russia']

req_data = data[data.NAME.isin(mycountries)]
req_data = req_data.reset_index()
req_data = req_data.drop('index',axis=1)

polygons = [req_data['geometry'][0],req_data['geometry'][1]]
boundary = gpd.GeoSeries(cascaded_union(polygons))
boundary.plot(color = 'black')
plt.show()
```

I require that when I calculate the distance of a point from the multipolygon, it should consider the closest country/polygon and the distance should be in miles/kms. Any help around this will be really appreciated.

I tried using distance function but the result which I am getting is not correct. Moreover, if I consider point somewhere in Indian Ocean, it gives result as 0 which is again not what I require.

Shape file can be downloaded from the **TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.zip** file available at ***http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php***

Comment: How do you define your distance from a point to a multipolygon?

Comment: I define distance from a point to a multipolygon as the minimum distance between the point and the nearest point on the boundary of the nearest polygon present in the plane of multipolygon. I hope this answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

here one solution using Point.distance:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
point = Point(34.23, 86.44)
dist={}
for index, row in req_data.iterrows():
    if row.geometry.geom_type == 'MultiPolygon':
        for  r in row.geometry:
            print(row.NAME,'  dist', point.distance(r))
            if row.NAME in dist:
                l = dist[row.NAME];l.append(point.distance(r))
                dist[row.NAME] = l
            else:
                dist[row.NAME] = [point.distance(r)]
    else: #Polygon
        print(row.NAME,'  dist', point.distance(row.geometry))
        dist[row.NAME] = [point.distance(row.geometry)]


for x in dist:
    print(x, min(dist[x]))
```

output: min distance from each country

```
 Canada 95.0619464401356
 Russia 12.118509615115519
```

Comment: I am trying to calculate the distance from point (52.2605,-50.581). Ideally, this point is very close to Canada, but the answer which I am getting is Canada : 143.34 and Russia : 91.88. Also, I am assuming the distance is in degrees and 1 degree ~ 69 miles. Right?

Comment: The distance is 60 miles nautic for 1 degree, its an approximation because the calculated distance is an euclidian distance of the orthogonal projection of the world (you are using). If you want a better precision, you have to transform all points (lat,long) in cartesian coord (x,y,z).  But that means to transform all yours multipolygons to polygons and finally to points -> long very, long time....